# Least Angle Regression for Complex Rational Models

Tags: complex-numbers, regression, ratio

**Background**

I am doing a project and need to fit the following rational model, where the terms $\Psi$s are real but $y$, $p$, and $q$ are complex:

$$
y_{i} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n_{p}}\Psi_{ij}p_{j}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{n_{q}}\Psi_{ik}q_{k}} 
\phantom{x}
\forall 
\phantom{x}i \in \left\{1,2,...,n\right\}
$$

The model is chosen because the underlying physics dictate that $y$ will take this form. There are limited observations so I wish to perform sparse regression to avoid overfitting.

**My Attempt So Far**

I tried to simplify by multiplying the equation with its denominator and rearranging the terms to obtain the following:

$$
0 = y_{i} - \sum_{j=1}^{n_{p}}\Psi_{ij}p_{j} + y_{i}\sum_{k=1}^{n_{q}}\Psi_{ik}q_{k}
\phantom{x}
\forall 
\phantom{x}i \in \left\{1,2,...,n\right\}
$$

Then I define a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{M}$ such that $M_{ii}=y_{i}$, a "regressor" matrix $\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\Psi}_{p}&-\mathbf{M}\mathbf{\Psi}_{q}\end{bmatrix}$, and the coefficient vector $\mathbf{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{p}^{T}&\mathbf{q}^{T}\end{bmatrix}^{T}$. Consequently, I can represent the equation using matrix-vector notation:

$$
\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta}
$$

Now that the equation takes the familiar form of linear regression, I thought it might be a good idea to use existing linear sparse regression algorithm e.g. LARS. Since the original algorithm is intended for real numbers, I modified it slightly to work with complex numbers:

***Initialise all coefficients with zeros***

Just like with LARS, the model is empty at the beginning and at each step the coefficients are modified
$$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}=\mathbf{0}\implies\hat{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{X}\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}=\mathbf{0}\implies\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{y}-\hat{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{y}$$

***Select regressor(s)***

The regressors are columns of $\mathbf{X}$. We choose column(s) $\mathbf{x}_{l}$ that maximize "covariance" $\left|\mathbf{x}_{l}^{H}\mathbf{e}\right|$. The chosen regressor(s) is stored in columns of $\mathbf{X}_{A}$

***Compute the next addition to the model***

The idea is to add coefficients of the regressors that have the largest covariance with the remaining error. Let the additional term be proportional to $\mathbf{u}_{A}=\mathbf{X}_{A}\mathbf{w}_{A}$. The weight $\mathbf{w}_{A}$ is chosen such that the covariances of all columns of $\mathbf{X}_{A}$ with the error decrease but remain equal. Normalising factor $\alpha$ is chosen such that $\|\mathbf{u}_{A}\|_{2}=1$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{w}_{A}&=\alpha\cdot\left(\mathbf{X}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{X}_{A}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{e}
\\
\alpha &= \left[\left(\mathbf{X}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{e}\right)^{H}\left(\mathbf{X}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{X}_{A}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{X}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{e}\right)\right]^{-0.5}
\end{aligned}
$$

***Add $\gamma\cdot\mathbf{u}_{A}$ to the model***

This step is equivalent to adding $\gamma\cdot\mathbf{w}_{A}$ to the coefficients associated with regressors that are chosen to be column of $\mathbf{X}_{A}$. The updated model and error are given below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\mathbf{y}}_{new}
&=
\hat{\mathbf{y}}_{old} + \gamma \mathbf{u}_{A} \\
&= 
\hat{\mathbf{y}}_{old} + \gamma \mathbf{X}_{A} \mathbf{w}_{A}\\
\\
\mathbf{e}_{new}
&=
\mathbf{e}_{old} - \gamma \mathbf{u}_{A}\\
&=
\mathbf{e}_{old} - \gamma \mathbf{X}_{A} \mathbf{w}_{A}
\end{aligned}
$$

The scalar $\gamma$ is chosen to be the smallest positive step until a new column of $\mathbf{X}$, denoted $\mathbf{x}_{r}$ has equal covariance with the error of all columns of $\mathbf{X}_{A}$,denoted $\mathbf{x}_{s}$.

$$
\|\mathbf{x}_{s}^{H}\mathbf{e} - \gamma \mathbf{x}_{s}^{H}\mathbf{u}_{A}\|_{2}
=
\|\mathbf{x}_{r}^{H}\mathbf{e} - \gamma \mathbf{x}_{r}^{H}\mathbf{u}_{A}\|_{2}
$$

This results in a quadratic equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 
&=
a\gamma^{2} + b\gamma + c
\\
\\
a &=
\alpha^{2}\cdot\mathbf{e}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{s}\mathbf{x}_{s}^{H}\mathbf{e}
-
\mathbf{u}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{r}\mathbf{x}_{r}^{H}\mathbf{u}_{A}
\\
b &=
2\Re{\left(\mathbf{u}_{A}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{r}\mathbf{x}_{r}^{H}\mathbf{e}\right)}
-2\alpha\cdot\mathbf{e}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{s}\mathbf{x}_{s}^{H}\mathbf{e}
\\
c &=
\mathbf{e}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{s}\mathbf{x}_{s}^{H}\mathbf{e}
-
\mathbf{e}^{H}\mathbf{x}_{r}\mathbf{x}_{r}^{H}\mathbf{e}
\end{aligned}
$$

We can solve the quadratic equation and select the smallest $\gamma$. Then we go back to step *"Select regressor(s)"* and loop until the error is small enough

**Results So Far**

I tried the algorithm to fit the model for mock observations using $4$ uniform random samples of $x$, the observations and models respectively:

$$y=\frac{1}{1+0.2x} \implies \hat{y}=\frac{0.98 + 0.0 x + 0.0 x^{2}}{1 + 0.199 x + 0.0 x^{2} + 0.0 x^{3}}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{1+0.2x^{2}} \implies \hat{y}=\frac{1.12 + 0.0 x + 0.0 x^{2}}{1 + 0.0 x + 0.198 x^{2} + 0.0 x^{3}}$$

The algorithm managed to consistently yield "accurate" model upon multiple repetitions. However, it failed for the following:

$$
y = \frac{1}{1+0.2x+0.4x^{2}}
$$

Upon repetitions, it yielded different non-zero coefficients for different terms each time. I though it may be because I have more coefficients and need more observations, however, increasing number of samples did not change anything.

**Question**

Is there any further modification I can apply to the algorithm to improve its performance, or is there any other algorithms that are better suited for this kind of problem?